# Comparing default-constructed iterators with operator==

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, stl, iterator

Does the C++ Standard say I should be able to compare two default-constructed STL iterators for equality?  Are default-constructed iterators equality-comparable?

I want the following, using std::list for example:

```
void foo(const std::list<int>::iterator iter) {
    if (iter == std::list<int>::iterator()) {
        // Something
    }
}

std::list<int>::iterator i;
foo(i);
```

What I want here is something like a NULL value for iterators, but I'm not sure if it's legal.  In the STL implementation included with Visual Studio 2008, they include assertions in std::list's operator==() that preclude this usage.  (They check that each iterator is "owned" by the same container and default-constructed iterators have no container.)  This would hint that it's not legal, or perhaps that they're being over-zealous.

Comment: `boost::optional<std::list::iterator>` comes to mind.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

OK, I'll take a stab. The C++ Standard, Section 24.1/5:

> Iterators can also have singular
>   values that are not associated with
>   any container. [Example: After the
>   declaration of an uninitialized
>   pointer x (as with int* x;), x must
>   always be assumed to have a singular
>   value of a pointer.  ] Results of most
>   expressions are undefined for singular
>   values; the only excep- tion is an
>   assignment of a non-singular value to
>   an iterator that holds a singular
>   value.

So, no, they can't be compared.

Comment: What about `std::istream_iterator.  That is exactly how you compare the test for end.

Answer (score 13):

This is going to change in C++14.  [forward.iterators] 24.2.5p2 of N3936 says

> However, value-initialized iterators may be compared and shall compare
>   equal to other value-initialized iterators of the same type.

Comment: I hit this right now when implementing something at work :( I was wishing I had c++2014 but just have visual studio 2012 :D

Comment: This is still not a good idea even in C++14 because non-singular iterators can't be compared against a value-initialized iterator.

Comment: No, this does not really change anyting. Just because you can compare two value-initialized iterators does not mean that you can compare a value-initialized iterator with some other iterator. You can't. In the latter case the behavior is still undefined even after C++14.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should pass a **range** to the function.

```
void fun(std::list<int>::iterator beg, std::list<int>::iterator end)
{
    while(beg != end)
    {
        // do what you want here.
        beg++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possibly true, but doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but the semantics really call for a single item -- much like std::list::erase().  I may be abusing the concept of an iterator; that's what I'm interested in discovering.

Comment: AraK, by what means can you have have a "null" iterator to pass in?

Comment: @Andy, I didn't understand your question.

Comment: The point is that range-function has the same problem - and gives a good reason for allowing the comparison in C++14.

You can default-construct 'beg' and 'end' in the calling routine (and then possibly set them to an actual range) and call 'fun'. That requires the same test between two default-constructed iterators 'beg' and 'end'.

(You cannot assume that the calling routine always has access to an appropriate container.)

Answer (score 1):

Specification says that the postcondition of default constructor is that iterator is [singular](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/trivial.html). The comparison for equality are undefined, so it may be different in some implementation.