# Is it well-defined to compare with a value-initialized iterator?

Tags: c++, c++11

Does the following program invoke undefined behavior?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    for (auto it = std::istream_iterator<std::string>(std::cin);
         it != std::istream_iterator<std::string>();
         ++it)
    {
        std::cout << *it << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This [4 year old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190112/comparing-default-constructed-iterators-with-operator) says that they can't be compared:

> Iterators can also have singular values that are not associated with
>   any container. [Example: After the declaration of an uninitialized
>   pointer x (as with int* x;), x must always be assumed to have a
>   singular value of a pointer. ] Results of most expressions are
>   undefined for singular values; the only excep- tion is an assignment
>   of a non-singular value to an iterator that holds a singular value.

But another answer for says for the C++14 standard:

> However, value-initialized iterators may be compared and shall compare
>   equal to other value-initialized iterators of the same type.

Comment: Not used to using iterators this way, when would the loop end (or you expect to)?

Comment: That loop is indeed well-defined, it's like any other iterator loop, you have its beginning and looping until its end. It's also very common to use the input stream iterators like that in calls to e.g. [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) to get all values from the stream into a vector for example, see for example the sample code in [this `std::istream_iterator` reference page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator).

Comment: I fear you are mixing compare iterators and compare values of dereferenced iterators, where dereferencing end() is undefined.

Answer (score 14):

You are conflating two different issues.

`istream_iterator` is an input iterator, not a forward iterator, so the C++14 change you cited doesn't apply to it at all. You are allowed to compare `istream_iterator`s in that manner because they are explicitly specified to allow such comparisons. The standard says that (§24.6.1 [istream.iterator])

> The constructor with no arguments `istream_iterator()` always
>   constructs an end-of-stream input iterator object, which is the only
>   legitimate iterator to be used for the end condition. [...]
>
> Two end-of-stream iterators are always equal. An end-of-stream
>   iterator is not equal to a non-end-of-stream iterator. Two
>   non-end-of-stream iterators are equal when they are constructed from
>   the same stream.

For forward iterators (which also includes bidirectional and random access ones) in general, value-initialized iterators are made comparable to each other in [C++14](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3644.pdf). If your standard library implements it, then you can compare two value-initialized iterators. This allows you to create an empty range without an underlying container. However, you are still not allowed to compare a non-singular iterator to a value-initialized iterator. The following code has undefined behavior even in C++14:

```
std::list<int> l;

if(l.begin() == std::list<int>::iterator())
    foo();
else 
    bar();
```