# Can I create an empty range (iterator pair) without an underlying container object?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

I have a class akin to the following:

```
struct Config
{
   using BindingContainer = std::map<ID, std::vector<Binding>>;
   using BindingIterator  = BindingContainer::mapped_type::const_iterator;

   boost::iterator_range<BindingIterator> bindings(ID id) const;
private:
   BindingContainer m_bindings;
};
```

Since the `ID` passed to `bindings()` might not exist, I need to be able to represent a 'no bindings' value in the return type domain.

I don't need to differentiate an unknown `ID` from an `ID` mapped to an empty `vector`, so I was hoping to be able to achieve this with the interface as above and return an empty range with default-constructed iterators. Unfortunately, although a `ForwardIterator` is `DefaultConstructible` [C++11 24.2.5/1] the result of comparing a singular iterator is undefined [24.2.1/5], so without a container it seems this is not possible.

I could change the interface to e.g wrap the `iterator_range` in a `boost::optional`, or return a vector value instead; the former is a little more clunky for the caller though, and the latter has undesirable copy overheads.

Another option is to keep a statically-allocated empty vector and return its iterators. The overhead wouldn't be problematic in this instance, but I'd like to avoid it if I can.

Adapting the `map` iterator to yield comparable default-constructed iterators is a possibility, though seems over-complex...

Are there any other options here that would support returning an empty range when there is no underlying container?

(Incidentally I'm sure a while back I read a working paper or article about producing empty ranges for standard container type when there is no container object, but can't find anything now.)

(Note I am limited to C++11 features, though I'd be interested if there is any different approach requiring later features.)

Comment: In my mind an empty range would be one where `begin` equals `end`.

Comment: [N3644](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3644.pdf). In C++14, value-initialized forward iterators can be compared to each other and must compare equal.

Comment: @Joachim - yes, that's what I'd like, but AFAICT I can't create that without a container due to the undefined result cited from the standard.

Comment: Thanks @T.C. that's exactly the paper I was thinking of.

Comment: You could use a `unique_ptr` to hold the pair, and leave it unitialized to represent 'no bindings'.

Comment: @JonathanPotter - that's equivalent in functionality as a `boost::optional`, but with added performance penalty and less accurate semantics.

Comment: @sp2danny the standard allows for default-constructed iterators (which are singular) to have uninitialised pointers internally, hence "the result of comparing a singular iterator is undefined".

Comment: @sp2danny On most modern implementations, `std::vector<T>::iterator` is *not* a `T*`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, there aren't. Your options are as you suggest. Personally, I would probably go with the idea of hijacking an iterator pair from a static empty vector; I can't imagine what notional "overhead" would be involved here, beyond a couple of extra bytes in your process image.

- [Is this a singular iterator and, if so, can I compare it to another one?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17198239/560648)
- [Comparing default-constructed iterators with operator==](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1190112/560648)

And this hasn't changed in either C++14 or C++17 (so far).

Answer (score 0):

You may use a default constructed `boost::iterator_range`

from (https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/utilities/iterator_range.html):

> However, if one creates a default constructed iterator_range, then one
>   can still call all its member functions. This design decision avoids
>   the iterator_range imposing limitations upon ranges of iterators that
>   are not singular.

Example here:
https://wandbox.org/permlink/zslaPwmk3lBI4Q9N

Comment: But, also, _"Any singularity limitation is simply propagated from the underlying iterator type"_, and note the final phrase in your quote, _"iterators that are not singular"_. The way I read it, this means the _range_ doesn't impose any constraints if singular, but if the underlying iterator is singular then you still must abide by those constraints. I don't quite understand it though because it would effectively make the paragraph pointless. Perhaps a default-constructed range just "bypasses" the encapsulated iterator entirely? Might be nice to get some clarification from the mailing list.

Comment: However this is promising! Let us know how it works out

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with @LightnessRacesinOrbit's interpretation of the docs there, so I don't think this is viable, but thanks anyway.

Comment: It works fine. While the documentation is a bit obfuscated it merely is talking about what happens if you default construct an iterator as compared to a default constructed `boost::range` and the fact that the underlying iterator is just propagated. Example here https://wandbox.org/permlink/zslaPwmk3lBI4Q9N